# Object Pointer Crash in UE4 for State Machine Behaviour

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Im trying to make a finite state machine behavior and i cant seem to wrap my head around UE4s c++
This is where I am initializing my states and setting it to the SMB

```
ATryEM::ATryEM()
{

    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;
    MyStateMachineBehaviour = NewObject<UMyStateMachineBehaviour>();
    testState = NewObject<UMyState>();
    otherState = NewObject<UMyState>();

    if(ensure(testState))
    MyStateMachineBehaviour->Init(testState);
    
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void ATryEM::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    ChangeState();
}

void ATryEM::ChangeState()
{
    if (ensure(otherState))
        MyStateMachineBehaviour->ChangeState(otherState);
}
```

This is how my SMB looks like

```
#include "MyStateMachineBehaviour.h"

UMyStateMachineBehaviour::UMyStateMachineBehaviour()
{
    CurrentState = nullptr;
}

void UMyStateMachineBehaviour::Init(UMyState* initState)
{
    if(initState)
    {
        CurrentState = initState;
        CurrentState->Enter_State();
    }
}

void UMyStateMachineBehaviour::ChangeState(UMyState* newState)
{
    CurrentState->Exit_State();
    if (newState)
    {
        CurrentState = newState;
        CurrentState->Enter_State();
    }
}

void UMyStateMachineBehaviour::UpdateState()
{
    if(CurrentState)
    CurrentState->Exit_State();
}
```

and the states just have a debug statement.

Comment: You're making objects with no outer, they are likely being garbage collected.

Comment: outer as in? Could you please elaborate?@Rotem

Comment: Try `NewObject<UMyState>(this);`. Give it a kind of parent that owns it so it doesn't get GC'ed.